# How to add to value from different tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

So let's say I had something that looked like this (example code):

```
public int val = 0;
public Task[] Tasks = new Task[3];

private void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Tasks.Count(); i++)
    {
        Tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            changeValue(val);
        });
    }
    foreach (var task in Tasks)
    {
        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

public static void changeValue(int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        value++;
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

In my case this caps the value at 100 because each task is changing it independently, but I want it to cap at 300 because there are 3 tasks (for this example) and I want them to change the value together.

Does anyone know what could help me with this? I've tried doing `public volatile int val`, and I tried making a lock method that changes the value but nothing worked.

Comment: lock statement or Interlocked static class should help

Comment: Also for example [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor).

Comment: @Serg thanks for the answer, turns out that's exactly what I needed as seen in the answer below

Comment: Please never ever code `catch { }` like that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing value by value, so val would never changed. This code snippet makes no sense for me, but passing by reference and Interlocked would do the job.

```cs
public class C1
{
    public int Val => val;
    private int val = 0;
    public Task[] Tasks = new Task[3];  // Why is this public?

    public async Task Run()
    {
        // <= is wrong!
        for (int i = 0; i < Tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            Tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                C2.ChangeValue(ref val);
            });
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
    }
}

public class C2
{
    public static void ChangeValue(ref int value)
    {
        // < instead of <=
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Interlocked.Add(ref value, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(value);  // Or Messagebox
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new C1();
        await c1.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot, the code snippet wasn't really meant to run I just quickly wrote that to get the idea across. I knew that I had to use Interlocked but I didn't understand how to approach that but this cleared that up